# Adding an item to a mutable list at index zero doesnt update the recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, mutablelist

I have a recyclerview inside a fragment that displays a mutable list of tasks that each have a title and description, wrapped in mutable live data.

`private val _tasks = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Task>>()`

To add those items, i implemented a bottom sheet dialog fragment with text edits for both values.

When i add a task item without specifying the index the recyclerview updates correctly :

`_tasks.value!!.add(Task(taskEditText,descriptionEditText))`

However, when i specify i want the new task item at index 0 and i add multiple task items, the recyclerview [displays the first task i added over and over.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aSUC.jpg)

Things i've tried:

Using notifyDataSetChanged inside the adapter works and updates the recyclerview correctly, however i tried adding it to my add task button inside my bottom sheet dialog and it does nothing.

I tried adding the items to a temporary list and then setting it to _tasks.value but the same thing happened, only updates when i dont specify the index.

Here are relevant files :

AddTaskFragment (Bottom Sheet Dialog) :

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    // if the textfields are not empty, adds the task and leaves the dialog
    binding.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener{
        if (binding.addTaskEditText.text!!.isNotEmpty() && binding.addDescriptionEditText.text!!.isNotEmpty()) {
            viewModel.addTask(binding.addTaskEditText.text.toString(), binding.addDescriptionEditText.text.toString())
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

addTask function inside viewmodel :

```
fun addTask(taskEditText : String, descriptionEditText : String) {
    _tasks.value!!.add(0,Task(taskEditText,descriptionEditText))
}
```

Adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val task = viewModel.tasks.value!![position]
    holder.itemTitle.text = task.text
    holder.itemDescription.text = task.description
    holder.textViewOptions.setOnClickListener {
        onMenuClick(position, holder, task)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance and i hope you pros can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
viewModel.tasks.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

What happens behind the scenes is that the list adapter checks if the oldList is the same as the new list reference, in your case that's the same list and as a result, it doesn't take any action (look through the code). But when the oldList is different from the newList in terms of reference, it updates the items in the recycler view. If you want to achieve that it's either you use immutability as a pattern for updating items in your UI or use other methods available in the recyclerview such as notifyItemInserted, notifyDataSetChanged, etc